# Update statement in Lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, lambda, sql-update

I would like to convert the following to lambda expression :

```
Update [ActivityTask] Set GroupID = "1" Where ActivityID = aid AND TaskID = tid ;
```

GroupID  = (an int that is taken from elsewhere , not hardcoded i put as 1 as an examle)

I really got stucked at how to continue with this ... i got the insert method :

```
public void Insert(ModelSQL.ActivityTask act)
{
    context.ActivityTasks.AddObject(act);
}
```

Wondering if it works the same as the top so i tried this :

```
    public void Update(int gid , int aid , int tid)
    {
        Update<ActivityTask>( new { x => x.GroupID == gid }).Where(x => x.activityID == aid && x.taskID == tid);
    }
```

But it gives error " Cannot assign lambda expression to anonymous " and i also cannot use 3 arguments ( 3 ints ) ..

Comment: Is context.ActivityTasks List of ActivityTask?

Answer (score 0):

If context.ActivityTasks is List then

```
public void Update(int gid , int aid , int tid)
{
    List<ActivityTask> found = context.ActivityTasks.FindAll(item => item.activityID == aid && item.taskID == tid);
    found.ForEach(item  => { item.GroupID = gid; });
}
```

For Entity framework multiple update see [Entity Framework Extensions (Multiple entity updates)](http://efe.codeplex.com/) It's Open Source. This allows update operations using lambda expressions.

```
using System.EntityFramework.Extensions.ObjectQueryExtensions; //Include this package
{
  ....

   public void Update(int gid , int aid , int tid)
   {
     context.ActivityTasks.Update(t => new ActivityTask() { GroupID = gid }, 
                                  t => t.activityID == aid && t.taskID == tid);     
   }
  ....
}
```

Comment: there is no Update after activitytask , i am using EF4 ... there is only Update<table> .. there is no FindAll too

Comment: @user2376998 I have updated the post and added reference where you can find the extensions to use update in EF